# CSS not applied to all elements

Tags: html, css, django

I generate the following HTML with Django:

```
<p>
    <label for="id_username">
        Username:
    </label>
    <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30"></input>
</p>
```

... and use the following CSS code to try to decorate labels and text inputs:

```
form.registration p label,
form.registration p input
{
    width: 250px;
}
```

In the end, the navigator (Firefox) only changes the width of the input text boxes, but not the one of the labels. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Does it not change the width *property* or does it not change the visible width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, the default display for `label` in most browsers is `display: inline`.  This means that a set width will not effect any changes.  Add `display: inline-block` to the properties (this won't affect the `<input>`, which are already `display: inline-block`)